# Excel VBA webpage control

Tags: javascript, excel, vba

[image]

I am trying to select dropdown values using vba. Tried the following options:

```
doc.getelementbyid("kyc_doc_required").value="ADDRESS PROOF"

doc.getelementbyid("kyc_doc_required").fireevent "onchange"
 
doc.getElementsByClassName("select2-search__field")(0).Click (same as doc.getelementbyid("kyc_doc_required"))
application.sendkeys "ADDRESS PROOF"
application.sendkeys "~",True
```

None of the above work. Below is the xml:

[image]

Comment: *None of the above work* is not helpful. What error message do you get?

Comment: That is html. Please insert the html using [edit] rather than posting a picture. There is a tool in edit toolbar called snippet you paste html into top left of. Looks like <>

Comment: Did you research SelectedIndex? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vba+select+option+dropdown   Or other methods for selecting from html select element with vba?

Comment: @StureS        There is no error, but is doesn't select any values

Comment: @QHarr          I have tried selectedindex, doesn't work for this field but it works for a usual combo box where you have to select only one value; here we can select multiple items in the same field

Comment: sendkeys work but that is the last thing i want   application.sendkeys "ADDRESS PROOF", True & then application.sendkeys "~",True